# jquery .height() and .width() on span tag gets inconsistent results

Tags: jquery, height, width, html

I need to get the dimensions of a variable-height-and-width element, `#sentence`, in order to change the dimensions of other elements that are related to it. `#sentence` is centered in the browser window, and its height and width are determined whatever its contents are. My code looks like this:

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="cell">
            <span id="sentence">
                sentence
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body, html  {
    font-size: 18pt;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#wrapper    {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
}
#cell   {
    display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;
}

#sentence   {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #abc;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var h = $("#sentence").height();
    alert(h);
});
```

When I try to get the `.height()` or `.width()` of `#sentence`, I get back inconsistent values. Usually for the height it's 28, but sometimes it comes back as 19. For the width, I get 84 or sometimes 52.

I thought that perhaps the difference was caused by scrollbars temporarily appearing and then disappearing when the page loads. I tried adding `overflow: hidden;` to `html` and `body` to get rid of any scrollbars that might be showing up, but that didn't work. I also tried adding

```
$(window).resize(function(){ 
    h = $("sentence").width(); 
});
```

That didn't work. Using `.css("height")` doesn't seem to work either.

So what will? Why am I having this problem? Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Comment: I would create a jsFiddle...you will get more help.

Answer (score 6):

For the dimensions to be correct the browser needs to have layed out and rendered the page.  This isn't necessarily true when the `.ready(...)` event is fired.

Try using `$(window).load(...)` instead.

Comment: If I swap them out, the code ceases to work at all. I think `.ready()` should be fine since it's getting a value at all, right?

Comment: Apparently it's not since you are getting random values!  I have managed to get .load() working myself...